# Pure css floating issue

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

I'm using the Pure CSS framework and my code looks like

```
<div class="container pure-g">

 <header class='pure-u-1'>
  <h1 class='logo'>
    <a href="#">TEST</a>
  </h1>
  <nav class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-horizontal">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Example Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Example Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
</div>
```

Here's a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ME4jv/

What I'm trying to do is line up the logo (to be floated left) with the navigation links (floated right), but both floating and the grid system aren't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to override the framework width declaration that has been assigned to the nav. Currently it is set to `100%;`. This is why it is not floating up.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/ME4jv/2/

```
.pure-menu.pure-menu-open {
    float:right;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Very minor thing, but `display: block` may not be necessary here.